# Zipping checkboxed files PHP

Tags: php, zip

```
   <?PHP
  function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path){
$zip = new ZipArchive();
//create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}
//add each files of $file_name array to archive
foreach($file_names as $files)  {
    $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);        
}
$zip->close();
$zipped_size = filesize($archive_file_name);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length:". " $zipped_size");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("$archive_file_name");
unlink("$archive_file_name"); // Now delete the temp file (some servers need this option)
exit;   
  }
if(($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
//$file_names=$_POST['items'];// Always sanitize your submitted data!!!!!!
//$file_names = filter_var_array($_POST['items']);//works but it's the wrong method
$filter = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) ;
$file_names = $filter['items'] ; 
//Archive name
$archive_file_name= "zip.zip";
//Download Files path
$file_path= $leadon;
//cal the function
zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$leadon);

}
?>
```

I have a working code here.

The main problem is

```
//Download Files path
$file_path= $leadon;
//cal the function
zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$leadon);
```

This code
echo $leadon;

```
 returns string images2/User/
```

And it doesn't create me the zip file ( well it creates a blank ) but if I manually type in the path
     "images2/User/"

into

$file_path= and then I just change

```
 zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);
```

everything works fine can you tell me why is it so? And how can I change it:s

Comment: where does $leadon come from? is it an actual string or an object or array that contains a string.

Comment: var_dump string(15) "images2/user/"
its from scandir it gets the path to a folder

Comment: yep, that's strange that it works when you hard code it but not when you use a reference. i'd suggest maybe putting a forward slash before it, but if you're hardcoding it without a starting slash, i dunno